# Find the distribution of $ Z=|X-Y|$ if $X=U(0,1), Y= U(0,3)$ X,Y- independent random variables.

Tags: probability, integration

Find the distribution of $ Z=|X-Y|$ if  $X=U(0,1), Y= U(0,3)$ X,Y- independent random variables...
K-relevant are. $W_1$-area bounded by $y_1, y_2$. $W_2$-area bounded by $y_3$ from above, $W_4$- area bounded by $y_4$ from above.

Now the answer goes on to find :$$F_z(t)=P\{X-t <Y<X+t\}= \iint_{W_1}f(x,y)dxdy= **{2 \over 3}t - {t^2\over 6}**, 0<t<1.$$ Here I got ${2\over 3 } t$

$$F_z(t)=P\{X-t <Y<X+t\}= \iint_{W_2}f(x,y)dxdy= **{t \over 3} - {1\over 6}**, 1<t<2.$$
$$F_z(t)=P\{X-t <Y<X+t\}= \iint_{W_3}f(x,y)dxdy= **{6t-t^2-3 \over  6}**, 2<t<3.$$

Can someone tell me how to get these answers ?
[image]

Comment: edited, small mistake

Comment: The figure says that the density $g$ of $U=Y-X$ is piecewise linear on $(-1,3)$ with $g(u)\propto u+1$ on $(-1,0)$, $g(u)\propto1$ on $(0,2)$ and $g(u)\propto3-u$ on $(2,3)$ hence the density $h$ of $Z=|U|$ is such that $h(z)\propto2-z$ on $(0,1)$, $h(z)\propto1$ on $(1,2)$ and $h(z)\propto3-z$ on $(2,3)$. Finally the constant of proportionality is $\frac13$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the rectangle $R:=[0,1]\times[0,3]$. We have to compute the area of the set
$$A_t:=\bigl\{(x,y)\in R\>\bigm|\>x-t\leq y\leq x+t\bigr\}$$
which depends on $t\in[0,3]$. The required distribution function is then given by
$$F_z(t)={1\over3}{\rm area}(A_t)\qquad(0\leq t\leq3)\ .$$
Since the shape of $A_t$ is different for the cases $0\leq t\leq1$, $1\leq t\leq2$, and $2\leq t\leq 3$ you need three figures, each of them showing $R$ and $A_t$ for $t$ in one of these intervals. In each of these cases compute ${\rm area}(A_t)$ using elementary geometry. Here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But when I integrate the first shape for example I do not get the required area.

Comment: I will type out how I integrate the first area, because it is important for me to use such a technique for the future, and maybe you could point out the mistake I make ?

Comment: $\iint_{W_1}f(x,y)dxdy={1 \over 3 }\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{x-t}^{x+t} dy= {1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}(x+t-x+t) dx= {2 \over 3}t \ $

Comment: I find the other area no problem, only with this one is it incorrect.

Comment: Check your integral boundaries! Maybe you forgot the little white triangle in the first figure.